# Hibernate Map Column

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have this table

```
create table person(
  name varchar(250);
  age integer;
  zipcode integer;
  address varchar(250)
);
```

Can I map in my entity some like this:

```
public class Address {
  private Integer zipCode;
private String address;
}

public class Person{
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  private Address address;
}
```

without create a new table to Address?

tks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can map entity inside entity without creating a new table.

We can do create Person table and inside Person, table creates Address table fields columns.

1) Address class embeddas inside Person class.

```
@javax.persistence.Embeddable
public class Address {
  private Integer zipCode;
private String address;
}
```

2) Person class.

```
 public class Person{
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  @Embedded // this annotation is optional
 private Address address;
}
```

Note: Add all JPA annotation which is required to create a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, name = "TYPE")

---Add

public class Person extends Address {
}